# How to migrate from hapi swagger UI 1.2 to 2.0 in node js?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert my swagger documentation to the 1.0 to 2.0 , How can I do that. I am using hapijs

Comment: Can you please show us what you have done to solve this issue?

Comment: actually now I am using swagger with old UI and now I want update it , so I am confuse how to it.